# How to search over all available IMAP folders in Java?

Tags: java, search, imap

I am trying to search messages with respect to email-id across all available IMAP folders without iterating each folder and search within that.

Is there any workaround to achieve this in Java?

Can we achieve this kind of search for Gmail at least?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail you can search the "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder.  With other IMAP servers you'll have to search each folder separately.

Comment: The right way to find allmail is to issue a list command and look for the folder  that's flagged "all". Its name depends on the server and UI language.

Comment: Also note the user may have disabled the All Mail folder, so be prepared to search iteratively if you can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply. I implemented in Java for All Mail and taken care of UI language. If we can't search each folder separately, is there any way to reduce server connections like connection pooling or something?